# Recognize and use Hardware RAID 5

Tags: 20.04, raid, raid5

### Should I abandon this setup altogether and just use software RAID?

I am running 20.04 LTS on a SSD and have 3 1TB drives setup with a RAID 5 array through Asus/AMD RAIDXpert.

I can see all the drives in gparted and lshw -C disk shows

```
      *-disk:0                  
       description: ATA Disk
       product: KINGSTON SV300S3
       physical id: 0
       bus info: scsi@1:0.0.0
       logical name: /dev/sda
       version: BBF0
       serial: 50026B7746002607
       size: 111GiB (120GB)
       capabilities: partitioned partitioned:dos
       configuration: ansiversion=5 logicalsectorsize=512 sectorsize=512 signature=f76fefc9
  *-disk:1
       description: ATA Disk
       product: WDC WD10EZEX-00B
       vendor: Western Digital
       physical id: 1
       bus info: scsi@2:0.0.0
       logical name: /dev/sdb
       version: 1A01
       serial: WD-WCC3FL8EZ2YN
       size: 931GiB (1TB)
       configuration: ansiversion=5 logicalsectorsize=512 sectorsize=4096
  *-disk:2
       description: ATA Disk
       product: WDC WD10EZEX-00B
       vendor: Western Digital
       physical id: 2
       bus info: scsi@4:0.0.0
       logical name: /dev/sdc
       version: 1A01
       serial: WD-WCC3FKE06EZ4
       size: 931GiB (1TB)
       configuration: ansiversion=5 logicalsectorsize=512 sectorsize=4096
  *-disk:3
       description: ATA Disk
       product: WDC WD10EZEX-00B
       vendor: Western Digital
       physical id: 3
       bus info: scsi@5:0.0.0
       logical name: /dev/sdd
       version: 1A01
       serial: WD-WCC3FL8EZLVA
       size: 931GiB (1TB)
       configuration: ansiversion=5 logicalsectorsize=512 sectorsize=4096
```

Here are the images from the RAID config utility that I accessed during bootup.
[LD View](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SjQye.jpg)
[LD Definition](https://i.stack.imgur.com/i7qoq.jpg)

I also saw this [AMD RAIDXpert driver (rcraid)](https://launchpad.net/%7Ethopiekar/+archive/ubuntu/rcraid?field.series_filter=focal) PPA and followed the instructions on the page, but am not sure what it did, if anything.

I also found this [rcraid on github](https://github.com/thopiekar/rcraid-dkms) but this was aimed at booting from RAID. I'm booting from the SSD and trying to use hardware RAID for storage. FYI, following those instructions prevented me from booting until I reverted the changes to grub through recovery mode.

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: If I'm using Hardware RAID shouldn't Ubuntu see those as One 2TB drive?

Answer (score 0):

This is not a real hardware RAID card in that it still needs OS support and is at least partly closed source software.

You would be better off using the software RAID capabilities of Linux itself, as made available to you in the Ubuntu installer or the OS after install, or else just expose them as separate devices.